# Is website return post data after returning 3rd party website

Tags: php, mysql, integration, payment-gateway

I am building Recharge Website.
So I am collecting information from the user like Mobile No./Operator/Amount. and when the user clicks on Pay button then website goes to Payment Gateway website (3rd Party website). and gives me success/fail response, If the status is success then I want the Users Post variables to form API call to other websites.

I am Storing Users information in Session by this code:

```
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $_SESSION['number'] = $_POST['number'];
    $_SESSION['option'] = $_POST['option'];
    $_SESSION['amount'] = $_POST['amount'];
  }
```

and return this data in Success URL like

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['number'];>
```

but. website does't shows the values.

so any other way to return variables after returning website from 3rd party website.

Comment: grammar and spelling corrections

Comment: do you use session_start() in both pages to start/resume the session? http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php